# Javascript Wait

Tags: javascript, html, wait

I am trying to make the script pause for about 1 second, then continue executing the script, but I can't seem to figure out how. Here is my code:

```js
function hello() {
  alert("Hi!")
  //I need about a 1 seconed pause here;
  alert("Hi again!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Say Hi!</button>
```

I already tried the following:

```js
function hello() {
  alert("Hi!")
  setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)//I thought this would wait, run the function, then return to the function hello()...
  alert("Hi again!")
}
function myFunction {
  a = document.getElementById("blank")
  a.innerHTML = "wait complete"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Say Hi!</button>
<div id="blank">
...
</div>
```

Comment: setTimeout is asynchronous, so it won't wait to continue running the script. You need to put your second alert in a separate function, then pass that as the callback parameter of your setTimeout call.

Comment: For a start, you've got a syntax error, missing empty parentheses after `myFunction`. Next, to clarify, setTimeout schedules a function call for later but then continues executing the rest of the script. Everything you want to delay needs to be in the function passed to setTimeout, you can't just make a function wait and continue later like that.

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track with the setTimeout function:

```js
function hello() {
  alert("Hi!")
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert("Hi again!");
  }, 1000)

}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Say Hi!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

An idiom that's becoming common as async/await is available in browsers it to make an async function and await a `pause()` function the returns a promise:

```js
let pause = (time) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))

async function hello() {
  console.log("Hi!")
  await pause(2000)
  console.log("Hi again!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hello()">Say Hi!</button>
```